# Google Maps not getting rendered in Ionic View

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework

I have a controller that loads Google Maps, it works the first time the view/controller gets invoked but when you navigate back to the page, the Google Map does not get renedered.

Controller.js

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $stateParams, ionicMaterialInk, $ionicLoading) {
    $scope.$parent.clearFabs();
    $scope.isExpanded = true;
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.$parent.hideHeader();
    }, 0);

   var init = function(){
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.3000, -120.4833);
        var styles = [{"featureType":"all","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"weight":"0.5"},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"labels.text","stylers":[{"lightness":"-50"},{"saturation":"-50"}]},{"featureType":"administrative.neighborhood","elementType":"labels.text","stylers":[{"hue":"#009aff"},{"saturation":"25"},{"lightness":"0"},{"visibility":"simplified"},{"gamma":"1"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"saturation":"0"},{"lightness":"100"},{"gamma":"2.31"},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"},{"lightness":"20"},{"gamma":"1"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"saturation":"-100"},{"lightness":"-100"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"landscape.man_made","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"lightness":"0"},{"saturation":"45"},{"gamma":"4.24"},{"visibility":"simplified"},{"hue":"#00ff90"}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"saturation":"-100"},{"color":"#f5f5f5"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels.text","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"},{"color":"#666666"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"saturation":"-25"}]},{"featureType":"transit.line","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"transit.station.airport","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"lightness":"50"},{"gamma":".75"},{"saturation":"100"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]}];

        var mapOptions = {
            center: myLatlng,
            zoom: 16,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            styles : styles,
            disableDefaultUI: true
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
            map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
            var myLocation = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude),
                map: map,
                title: "My Locations"
                });
            });

        $scope.map = map;
        });
    }
    init();
    ionicMaterialInk.displayEffect();
})
```

Page.html

```
<ion-view view-title="Login" align-title="left" ng-init="init()">
<ion-content ng-class="{expanded:$scope.isExpanded}">
   <div id="map">
    </div>
    <div class="hero no-header flat">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="fa fa-taxi fa-3x" style="color:#D3D3D3"></div>
            <h1 id="logo" >Metro</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

<div id="over_map">
    <!-- <div class="list">
        <ion-md-input placeholder="Pickup Location" highlight-color="balanced" type="text"></ion-md-input> 
        <ion-md-input placeholder="Destination" highlight-color="balanced" type="text"></ion-md-input>            
    </div> -->
    <div class="padding">
        <button ui-sref="app.profile" class="button button-full button-balanced ink">Search</button>
    </div>
</div>

    <div class="button-bar social-login">
        <button class="button button-small button-border icon-left ion-social-google button-assertive-900">Google+</button>
        <button class="button button-small button-border icon-left ion-social-twitter button-calm-900">Twitter</button>
        <button class="button button-small button-border icon-left ion-social-facebook button-positive-900">Facebook</button>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `google.maps.event.trigger( map, 'resize' );` after the `$scope.map = map;` line.

UPDATE:

Try

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $stateParams, ionicMaterialInk, $ionicLoading) {
    $scope.$parent.clearFabs();
    $scope.isExpanded = true;
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.$parent.hideHeader();
    }, 0);

   var init = function(){
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.3000, -120.4833);
        var styles = [{"featureType":"all","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"weight":"0.5"},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"labels.text","stylers":[{"lightness":"-50"},{"saturation":"-50"}]},{"featureType":"administrative.neighborhood","elementType":"labels.text","stylers":[{"hue":"#009aff"},{"saturation":"25"},{"lightness":"0"},{"visibility":"simplified"},{"gamma":"1"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"saturation":"0"},{"lightness":"100"},{"gamma":"2.31"},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"},{"lightness":"20"},{"gamma":"1"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"saturation":"-100"},{"lightness":"-100"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"landscape.man_made","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"lightness":"0"},{"saturation":"45"},{"gamma":"4.24"},{"visibility":"simplified"},{"hue":"#00ff90"}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"saturation":"-100"},{"color":"#f5f5f5"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels.text","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"},{"color":"#666666"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"saturation":"-25"}]},{"featureType":"transit.line","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"transit.station.airport","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"lightness":"50"},{"gamma":".75"},{"saturation":"100"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]}];

        var mapOptions = {
            center: myLatlng,
            zoom: 16,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            styles : styles,
            disableDefaultUI: true
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
            map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
            var myLocation = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude),
                map: map,
                title: "My Locations"
                });
            });

        $scope.map = map; 
        google.maps.event.trigger( map, 'resize');

      });
    }


    $scope.$on("$ionicView.enter", init);
    ionicMaterialInk.displayEffect(); 
})
```

Comment: That did not help either

Comment: I edited your code a little bit...maybe it works now

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code. You  probably missing the height and width of `map` div. 
I have removed ionic framework module just to make my code work but that will not affect here. The missing thread was height and width to map

```
#map {
   height:420px;
   width:600px;
}
```

Checkout below

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
 
myApp.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
   
   
   var init = function(){
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.3000, -120.4833);
        var styles = [{"featureType":"all","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"weight":"0.5"},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"labels.text","stylers":[{"lightness":"-50"},{"saturation":"-50"}]},{"featureType":"administrative.neighborhood","elementType":"labels.text","stylers":[{"hue":"#009aff"},{"saturation":"25"},{"lightness":"0"},{"visibility":"simplified"},{"gamma":"1"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"saturation":"0"},{"lightness":"100"},{"gamma":"2.31"},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"},{"lightness":"20"},{"gamma":"1"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"saturation":"-100"},{"lightness":"-100"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"landscape.man_made","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"lightness":"0"},{"saturation":"45"},{"gamma":"4.24"},{"visibility":"simplified"},{"hue":"#00ff90"}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"saturation":"-100"},{"color":"#f5f5f5"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels.text","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"},{"color":"#666666"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"saturation":"-25"}]},{"featureType":"transit.line","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"transit.station.airport","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"lightness":"50"},{"gamma":".75"},{"saturation":"100"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]}];

        var mapOptions = {
            center: myLatlng,
            zoom: 16,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            styles : styles,
            disableDefaultUI: true
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
            map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
            var myLocation = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude),
                map: map,
                title: "My Locations"
                });
            });

        $scope.map = map;
        });
    }
    init();
})
```

```css
#map {
    height:420px;
    width:600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&sensor=false&extension=.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>


  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
    <div id="map"></div>
  </div>
```

Code pen here http://codepen.io/JoyCoder/pen/XmYppP